# How to add privacy indicators on Flutter iOS apps

Tags: ios, flutter

I developed an app that makes audio and video recording.

When submitting my app for review for App store, I was required to make sure the phone/devices will show [privacy indicators](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211876#:%7E:text=With%20iOS%2014%20or%20later,being%20used%20by%20an%20app) when using either the microphone or the camera:
[privacy indicators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPQTq.png)

I am using the packages [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound/versions/9.1.7) version 9.1.7 for audio recording and [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/versions/0.9.4+18) version 0.9.4+18 for video recording.

Can anyone help me on how to add those indicators. Every method is welcomes, even if it implies changing the package used for recording.

Thanks a lot.

I checked the packages changelog to see if it has been added at any point but I don't seem to see it added anywhere.

Comment: It is automatic

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is automatic as you said. My error was that the status bar background color was one that did not make it easy to see the indicator